# How to swap column1 value with colum 2 value under a condition in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to swap column1 value with column2 value if `column1.value >= 14` in pandas!

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 16 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 |

This should become:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 16 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 |

Thanks!

Comment: Please prove to us that you have tried a little yourself and show us the code you have written so far

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) and re-assign the two columns values:

```
m = df["col1"].ge(14)

out = df.assign(
                col1=df["col1"].mask(m, df["col2"]),
                col2=df["col2"].mask(m, df["col1"])
                )
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2
0     1    16
1     3     2
2     4     3
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple one liner solution,

```
df.loc[df['col1'] >= 14,['col1','col2']] = df.loc[df['col1'] >= 14,['col2','col1']].values
```